# accessing array data from stdCass Object in php

Tags: php, xml, object, soap

I got a reply from a SOAP client but instead of returning XML data, they are returning the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ConsumerIDVerificationResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [any] => <modules xmlns=""><ReportURL>http://test- 
bureau.tpn.co.za/viewLnk.aspx/Kn69EbQe</ReportURL><PdfURL>http://test- 
bureau.tpn.co.za/rpt.aspx/Kn69EbQe</PdfURL><summary><node name="NationalId"/><node name="Full 
Name">Jose Smit</node><node name="Active Companies">2</node><node name="InActive 
Companies">0</node><node name="Accounts">0</node><node name="TPN Payments">3</node><node 
name="Judgements">0</node><node name="Defaults">0</node><node name="Notices">0</node><node 
name="TraceAlerts">0</node><node name="Enquiries">0</node></summary><result><sessionid/> 
<enquiryid>3e51556a-8104-4022-becd-cba4fe75acaf</enquiryid></result></modules>
        )

)
```

How do I access for example the value of Full Name and the value of Active Companies as per above using PHP code? I only know how to access if it was XML using SimpleXMLElement but this is not XML!

Comment: Where's the code where you are making the request?

Comment: Above is the information that is returned.  I need to know how to access it i.e. the Full Name.

Comment: `$var->ConsumerIDVerificationResult->any`